# Self relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to add a self relation in an existing Innodb table here is table structure

```
Table person

   person_id int (10) primary key not null auto increment,

   parent_id int (10) NULL default null,

   name varchar(30)
```

When I use this command

```
ALTER TABLE `person` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `parent_id` ) REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT ;
```

I get the error data type mismatch. I think this could be due to null values in parent_id. Is there any way to skip this check?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

person_id and parent_id need to be the exact same data type. For example, if person_id is INT UNSIGNED and parent_id is INT, then you can't create the foreign key.

Run this command and compare the data types of the two columns:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `person`\G
```

Comment: There was unsigned different in both :)